# Deserialisation of list of timestamp in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have a dataframe containing a list of Timestamp. I serialize it with `to_csv` function and want to get it back with `read_csv`. I only got a column of type string like that :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':["[]", "[Timestamp('2018-04-24 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-05-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-05-14 00:00:00')]"]})
```

I tried to get the column into list of timestamp via and `str.extractall(r"Timestamp('\d-\d-\d 00:00:00)")` then `map(lambda lst : [pd.to_datetime(y), for y in lst]`

For now, the `extractall` function does not work.

Can you help me ?
Thank you

Comment: Did you mean to use `Timestamp\('\d+-\d+-\d+ 00:00:00'\)`? `\d` only matches one digit and you missed a `'` at the end before `)`.

Comment: of course, because csv is a totally inappropriate way to serialize your dataframe if you have a list of anything in your dataframe. You should use some other serialization format (e.g. `pickle` or perhaps `parquet`, and you should reconsider whether you should have a `list` of `TimeStamp` objects at all)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have string representations of lists of timestamps, you can combine [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html), [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
df['out'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['col'].str.extractall(r"Timestamp\('(\d+-\d+-\d+ 00:00:00)'\)")[0])
               .groupby(level=0).agg(list).reindex(df.index, fill_value=[])
            )
```

Output:

```
                                                                                                      col                                                              out
0                                                                                                      []                                                               []
1  [Timestamp('2018-04-24 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-05-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-05-14 00:00:00')]  [2018-04-24 00:00:00, 2018-05-14 00:00:00, 2018-05-14 00:00:00]
```

---

###### original answer

You have several issues, your regex is incorrect (unescaped parentheses, missing capturing group, missing `+` after `\d`…), also, use [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert back to datetime:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': ["Timestamp('2018-04-24 00:00:00')",
                                 "Timestamp('2018-05-14 00:00:00')",
                                 "Timestamp('2018-05-14 00:00:00')"]
                  })

df['out'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'].str.extract(r"Timestamp\('(\d+-\d+-\d+ 00:00:00)'\)", expand=False))
```

You could avan simplify the regex to `r"Timestamp\('([^)']+)'\)"` since the serialized format is supposedly valid.

Another strategy would be to specify the `%Y-%m-%d` format in `to_datetime` together with `exact=False` and let pandas find the date:

```
df['out'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d', exact=False)
```

Output:

```
                          timestamp        out
0  Timestamp('2018-04-24 00:00:00') 2018-04-24
1  Timestamp('2018-05-14 00:00:00') 2018-05-14
2  Timestamp('2018-05-14 00:00:00') 2018-05-14
```

---

If you have lists of timestamps as items, the logic is roughly the same.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': [["Timestamp('2018-04-24 00:00:00')",
                                  "Timestamp('2018-05-14 00:00:00')",
                                  "Timestamp('2018-05-14 00:00:00')"]]
                  })

def to_dt(lst):
    return pd.to_datetime(lst, format='%Y-%m-%d', exact=False).tolist()

df['out'] = df['timestamp'].apply(to_dt)
```

Output:

```
                                           timestamp                                                out
0  [Timestamp('2018-04-24 00:00:00'), Timestamp('...  [2018-04-24 00:00:00, 2018-05-14 00:00:00, 201...
```

Comment: Thank you, but there is no list here. The aim is to convert each cell containing a string representing a list of timestamp to a list of timestamp

Comment: @Nicolas can you provide a [mre] as `DataFrame` constructor in your question? That said the logic is similar (see update).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that solves my issue :

```
df['x'] = df['x'].str.extractall(r"Timestamp\('(\d+-\d+-\d+) 00:00:00'\)") \
                                                        .apply(pd.to_datetime, axis=1) \
                                                        .groupby(level=0)[0].apply(list)
```

and to optimize computation time, you can apply pd.to_datetime in all series instead of using apply